# I have multiple OSes on my computer, but cannot boot all of them

Tags: multi-boot, grub

I have installed Windows, BlackArch, and Fedora on my 1TB HDD on my Asus Q302LA 2-in-1 laptop.

I am trying to configure GRUB to be able to include all of the OSes that are on my hard disk.

Currently, I cannot get GRUB to show all of the options when GRUB boots up, and I need to be able to switch between them at will. I can only choose between Fedora and Windows (on the GRUB2 installation for Fedora) or BlackArch on the GRUB installation for BlackArch.

Is there any way to remedy this situation?

Comment: For multiple boot, certainly more than two, use Virtual Machines. Best way forward.

Comment: I understand that it is the best way forward, but I wanted a challenge... I am doing some research and may be able to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB has an in-built utility called `os-prober` which should detect all the three OSes.  You need to install GRUB in the same drive where the OSes reside.  Don't install it in a partition.  You should get these two options during the installation of one of the Linux OSes.  You can install GRUB again using a live image, I chose Kubuntu because it is easy enough and set up.

On my laptop, I've Windows 10 and Kali Linux on an HDD and Kubuntu 22.04 on an SSD.  All three are detected fine.  I've installed GRUB on the HDD, but it is able to pick up Kubuntu on the SSD too.